# Jquery ajax perform sequentially response

Tags: jquery, ajax

In my plugin I'd like to sequentially ajax call and response, because the next response depends to the previous.
Unfortunately, the responses do not match the call order (I don't want to use  async: false) and so I should handle this thing.

```
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c', ...]; <- dynamic values
var params = ['foo', 'bar', 'doe', ...]; <- dynamic values
var postData = {};

$.each ( array, function ( idx, val ) {
    postData.value = val;
    var param = params[idx];
    ajaxRequest( param, callback );
});

var ajaxRequest = function ( param, callback ) {
    $.ajax ({
        url: url,
        data: postData,
        type: "POST"
    }).done ( function ( data ) {
        //a returned data in 5 sec
        //b returned data in 3 sec
        //c returned data in 1 sec
    });
}
```

I have read some things about ajax promise and deferred, but I do not know IF and HOW it can be the correct solution for my scenario
How could I do this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "done" function of the ajax request to ensure the requests are chained together sequentially, since this callback doesn't execute until the request has successfully completed. Something like this (un-tested):

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', ...];
var params = ['foo', 'bar', 'doe', ...];
var arrIndex = 0;

function ajaxRequest() {
   console.log("Request " + arrIndex + " starting");
    var postData = { value: arr[arrIndex] };
    var param = params[arrIndex];

    $.ajax ({
        url: url,
        data: postData,
        type: "POST"
    }).done ( function ( data ) {
      console.log("Request " + arrIndex + " completed");
      arrIndex++;
      if (arrIndex < arr.length) {
        ajaxRequest();
      }
      else {
          console.log("All requests completed");
      }
    });
}
```

I'm not sure what the purpose of "param" is, because you don't seem to use it in the example, but I've left it in, in case you need it in reality. "callback" seemed to do nothing at all, so I've ignored that.

You probably also want to consider what to do if any particular request fails - I assume you can't continue, so maybe you just need to log the error, but I'll leave that to you.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but the problem is how to handle your code by calling ajaxrequest from a each loop. Params and callback, which I omitted are important in my code.

Comment: This logic is equivalent to the each loop. Essentially, each call to "ajaxRequest()" is equivalent to one iteration of the "loop", and the counter (arrIndex) is incremented manually each time. I have kept the "params" object as you see, so you can add in yourself whatever you need to do with it, but I ignored "callback" because I couldn't even see how it was defined, never mind how it was being used, so it was difficult to know how/where to include it. Either you can put it back in yourself, or if you explain it more I can try and make it fit logically into this.

Comment: I understand the logic. I need to check how to modify the methods of my plugin to handle it this way. The callback must define on done request. Promise and deferred in this case it can not be used? Thanks

Comment: $.ajax returns a deferred object / promise - that's why you can use .done() with it.